# SQL Order By two columns different ways in the same table.

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by

So I have seen a lot of examples and I just am not getting the deserved results. My table has a name column and then a (bool) activation column. I want to sort alphabetically ASC and then I want all the active on top so activation DESC.

`ORDER BY [eventName] ASC, [eventActivation] DESC`

the results of this I want should be

```
NAME | ACTIVATE
Ash      1
Jerry    1
Sam      1
Bruce    0
David    0
```

but I don't get this instead I get the results in only alphabetical.

Any help on this one? From everything I have seen it seems as though I am doing this right but I have to be missing something. Do I have to group by first? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be

```
ORDER BY [eventActivation] DESC, [eventName] ASC
```

Comment: I would up vote this because it worked! but why did the Doing the DESC first matter? Thanks again for that.

Comment: Because that is the natural order that you want the results to be sorted in